# how to validate sign in form using login def

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout false
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
        @user = User.create(user_params)
        redirect_to user_params
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # redirect_to user_params
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  def login
    @message = "hello"
    @user = User.where(email: params[:email], password: params[:password])
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name, :contact, :address, :email, :password)
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'users#new'
  resources :users
  get '/users:id', to: 'users#destroy', as: 'delete'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [`Devise`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#getting-started) gem for User authentication. It takes care of User registration, User sign in, etc. By using Devise gem, you will not end up creating what already exist.

**Steps are as follows:**

- Add the following line to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'devise'
```

Then run `bundle install`

- Run the generator:

```
$ rails generate devise:install
```

- Create devise `User` model with routes configured in `config/routes.rb` file

```
$ rails generate devise User
```

Run `rails db:migrate`

- To set up a controller with user authentication, just add this before_action

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

**Added advantage of using `Devise` gem are:**

- Helper methods are available

```
user_signed_in?
current_user
user_session
```

- In case you want to permit additional parameters

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

- Can generate devise views and controllers for customization

```
$ rails generate devise:views users
$ rails generate devise:controllers users
```

Find out more about Devise gem here: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#getting-started